<div> not aligning vertically for the first time only on mobile device
I'm encountering a very weird behavior while developing a website.
The plan is to load the website with a custom loading animation (vertically and horizontally aligned in the center of the screen) for a couple of seconds and then fade website content into view.
On web it worked and all resolutions on devtools worked perfectly.
However, now I just tested it on an actual mobile phone and there seems to be a very weird thing happening.
So, if you load the website freshly from a new tab, the loader is correctly horizontally aligned however is not vertically aligned, it is placed lower (like 50px lower). However, if I just touch the screen, the loader goes right in the middle as it should have initially been.
Then, if I reload the website (from the same tab), the loader is placed in the center correctly.
As I said, this is only happening on a real mobile device, not because of small resolution cause of a browser with mobile dev it works.
This is the HTML:
<body>
    <div class="preloader-container">
        <div class="spinner-container"></div>
    </div>
</body>

CSS:
body {
    background: var(--dark-grey);
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

.preloader-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: -webkit-fill-available; /* Also tried vw but same issue */
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available; /* Also tried vh but same issue */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

.spinner-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px solid var(--primary-colour);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    animation: spinAnimation 1s linear infinite;
}


What meta tags do you have in your head element?

@AHaworth just a viewport with user-scalable=no, nothing special..

